# Splash Screen Delay timer wait till permission dialog close in android

Tags: android, timer, gps

I am collecting GPS location data in Splash Screen and store it in session, and use it later in `MainActivity`. If the GPS is turn off or used for the first time it will ask for permission in my splash screen. The problem is that I am using the timer to move splash screen Activity to another activity. Due to the timer, SplashScreen is moving to next the activity without the permission. I want my Splash screen to wait till permission dialog is allowed or denied. Below is my code

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import zesteve.com.myapplication.location.LocationTrack;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;


public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView welcomeText;
    ImageView mLogo;
    ImageView zbgimg;

    Typeface tf1;

    private Session session;

    private ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;
    private ArrayList<String> permissionsRejected = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    private final static int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
    LocationTrack locationTrack;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        session = new Session(SplashActivity.this);

        //GPS Tracker
        permissions.add(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissions.add(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);
        //get the permissions we have asked for before but are not granted..
        //we will store this in a global list to access later.

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0)
                requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
        }

        locationTrack = new LocationTrack(SplashActivity.this);

        if (locationTrack.canGetLocation()) {
            double longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
            double latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();

            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(SplashActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String subLocality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String countryn = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();


                session.setLocation(latitude,longitude,locality,subLocality);

                //Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,locality +" "+ postalCode + " " + latitude+ " " + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            locationTrack.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        welcomeText.setTypeface(tf1);
        mLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.applogo);
        zbgimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zbgimg);
        zbgimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash_screen_option_three);


        animation2();
        animation3();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (session.FbLoggedIn()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
                }

            }

        }, 3000);
    }


    private void animation2() {
        mLogo.setAlpha(1.0F);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashActivity.this, R.anim.translate_top_to_center);
        mLogo.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    private void animation3() {
        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(welcomeText, "alpha", 0.0F, 1.0F);
        alphaAnimation.setStartDelay(1700);
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(500);
        alphaAnimation.start();
    }


    ///GPS Tracker
    private ArrayList<String> findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList<String> wanted) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String perm : wanted) {
            if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
                result.add(perm);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        if (canMakeSmores()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean canMakeSmores() {
        return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT:
                for (String perms : permissionsToRequest) {
                    if (!hasPermission(perms)) {
                        permissionsRejected.add(perms);
                    }
                }

                if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {


                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }

                break;
        }

    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationTrack.stopListener();
    }
```

If you do not understand please comment.

Comment: Using timer in splash screen itself is a bad implementation. If you have server interaction, or according to your problem, move to next screen only when all your conditions are met.

Comment: i added my full splash screen code have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution.

First of all, make your `onCreate()` method this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    session = new Session(SplashActivity.this);

    //GPS Tracker
    permissions.add(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    permissions.add(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);
    //get the permissions we have asked for before but are not granted..
    //we will store this in a global list to access later.

    welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    welcomeText.setTypeface(tf1);
    mLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.applogo);
    zbgimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zbgimg);
    zbgimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash_screen_option_three);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0)
            requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
    }
    else {
        animation2();
        animation3();
        setUserLocation();   //After that start app
    }

}
```

Then make separate `setUserLocation()` function outside of onCreate() as follow:-

```
public void setUserLocation() {

    locationTrack = new LocationTrack(SplashActivity.this);

    if (locationTrack.canGetLocation()) {
        double longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
        double latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(SplashActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String subLocality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String countryn = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

            session.setLocation(latitude,longitude,locality,subLocality);

            //Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,locality +" "+ postalCode + " " + latitude+ " " + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        startApp();

    } else {
        locationTrack.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

One more separate function `startApp()` outside onCreate() like below:-

```
public void startApp() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (session.FbLoggedIn()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
            }

        }

    }, 3000);
}
```

And last thing, change **`onRequestPermissionsResult()`** method like below:-

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT:
        for (String perms : permissionsToRequest) {
            if (!hasPermission(perms)) {
                permissionsRejected.add(perms);
            }
        }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
               animation2();
               animation3();
               setUserLocation();   //After that start app
            }
        }
        else {
            animation2();
            animation3();
            setUserLocation();   //After that start app
        }
            break;
    }

}
```

So, this solution follow permission first, then user-Location and then startApp.

Comment: If you want to remove handler, you can and directly you can condition and go to next activity.

Comment: hi i tried your solution its not starting activity after splach screen. when i press back button its closed with message application is stoped. in log cat i got error        Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@zesteve.com.myapplication-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied

Comment: When you press back button?

Comment: its was stuck at splash screen for long time so i pressed back button its sopped and shown the message

Comment: Have you try with remove handler and put direct code?

Comment: you code is working when the permission was not set. if the permission is allowed by user its not working. that means its working for only first time.

Comment: I will check and change condition in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` after few minutes..Or you can change that over there and try it.

Comment: Try new updated `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144454/discussion-between-nitin-patel-and-asesha-george).

Comment: OK. Did you remove handler and put direct condition and try?

Comment: its working now, i changed the  place of setUserLocation() in first part of your answer. else should be place after if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0)  condition. now its working.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to access location before going jumping from splash screen. If so just remove timer open and as splash screen opens make it check for location service on/off and get location and then jump to another activity.

```
if (!canGetLocation()) {
     showSettingsAlert();
} else {
     fetch location
     if (session.FbLoggedIn()) {
           startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
           finish();
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
     } else {
           startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
           finish();
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
    }
}
```

Comment: you understood correctly. but you answer is not working